# SQL - need a query to get most recent message in each thread that a user is part of

Tags: sql, t-sql, messaging

In my app, a "message thread" is defined as all messages between two or more users, and is not nested. It needs to work like Facebook messages.

I need a query that generates a list of all "message threads" in which a user is a member, sorted by threads with the most recent activity, descending. The result is a table of distinct threads, where each row contains the threadID, postDate and messageBody.

Here's my schema:

**MessageThreads** (threadID, lastPostDate)
**MessageThreadUsers** (threadFK, userFK)
**Messages** (messageID, threadFK, senderFK, postDate, messageBody)
**Users** (userID, userName, userEmail, ...)

To start with, this query gives me all messages from all threads that the user is in:

```
SELECT * FROM MessageThreadUsers
JOIN Messages ON MessageThreadUsers.threadFK = Messages.threadFK
WHERE MessageThreadUsers.userFK = 'usr_developer'
ORDER BY messageDate DESC
```

But how would I get only the most recent? I think I would use the MAX(messageDate) function, but how does that work in a JOIN like this? And how would I pull a single row with message data for each thread?

It would help quite a bit if you can post your answer in TSQL, but any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right order, you should get the "top hit" by adding:

```
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm thinking that limiting the result set would be done for the final set of threads as I page the results where MAX () would give me the latest post. But this answer doesn't get to the heart of the problem, which is: how would I join only the most recent message from a thread into a list of threads?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be not as difficult as I first thought. Because the most recent post date is being stored in the thread, I don't have to aggregate on the messageDate in the Messages table. Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MessageThreadUsers.threadFK, 
    MessageThreads.threadDate, 
    [Messages].MessageBody, 
    [Messages].senderFK,
    Users.userFullName
FROM MessageThreadUsers
JOIN MessageThreads ON MessageThreadUsers.threadFK = MessageThreads.threadID
JOIN Messages ON MessageThreads.threadDate = Messages.messageDate
JOIN Users ON Messages.senderFK = Users.userID
WHERE userFK = 'usr_developer'
```